# HTML/JavaScript - Value of Input doesn't update (Element.value = Null)

Tags: javascript

Hello I just started today so im pretty new.

I have to get a string, which a user can enter on the website into my JavaScript file. I found out that I should use `document.getElementById("myID").value` to get the value of an input field on the html site. Here is my problem: I can't use the  brackets arround my input and button because a submit will force a reload of the site and my functions wont have any affect.

So I have to get the string on the fly into my JavaScript file.

This is all I have at the moment:

```
<div id="searchDiv">
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search for Gifs..." value="" />
  <input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search"></button>
</div>
```

And my JavaScript file:

```
var searchButton = document.getElementById("searchButton");
var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;

searchButton.addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    function(parameter)
  }
)...
```

So `document.getElementById("searchInput").value;` give back null even if the input field has been edited.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Are you getting *null* or an empty string?

Comment: An empty string but the problem was that i accessed the value before someone even entered anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your are storing the searchInput value even before the button is clicked,so the value would be empty irrespective of anything that you enter as input

Try accessing on the click event of the button

check this snippet

```js
var searchButton =document.getElementById("searchButton");
var searchInput=document.getElementById("searchInput");
window.onload=function(){
searchButton.addEventListener("click",
  function() {
   alert(searchInput.value);
  }
)
}
```

```html
<div id="searchDiv">
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search for Gifs..." value="" />
  <input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search">

</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<button></button>
```

Instead of

```
<input></button>
```

What I did was

```
<div id="searchDiv">
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search for Gifs...">
        <button id="searchButton">Search</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("searchButton").onclick = function(){
            alert(document.getElementById("searchInput").value);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Yeah im playing around with this for hours now haha